# How to change folder names based off of a file name that changes (part number) in batch

Tags: batch-file

Here is what I have so far. I have some things commented out in my code but I figured that I would show it anyway for the process flow.

```
@echo off
COLOR 0A

::This is a User prompt.
echo INSERT SA KEY INTO COMPUTER BFORE CONTINUING!
echo.
pause
cls

::This is a User prompt.
echo READY TO RUN EIS ANALYSIS FILE FOLDER PREP!
echo.
pause
cls

::This opens folders needed to perform EIS analysis.
START "" "\\SE\data\PSC_CAMS_DATA\PSC_CAMS\READY_FOR_ANALYSIS"
START "" "C:\INLET\MEASURED"
START "" "C:\INLET"

::This is a User prompt.
::REM echo COPY JOB FOLDER CONTENTS FROM "READY_FOR_ANALYSIS FOLDER"
::REM echo.
::REM echo PASTE INTO "EIS_DATA" FOLDER ON DESKTOP.
::REM echo.
::REM echo PLACE INITIALS IN FRONT OF JOB FOLDER IN "READY FOR ANALYSIS"
::REM echo.
::REM pause
::REM cls

::REM This is a User prompt.
::REM echo CREATING ANALYSIS FOLDER STRUCTURE!
::REM echo.
::REM echo COPYING JOB FOLDER DATA TO C:\INLET!
::REM echo.
::REM echo COPYING JOB FOLDER DATA TO "EIS ARCHIVE"!
::REM echo.
::REM echo "THIS OPERATION WILL TAKE A FEW SECONDS, WAIT FOR PROMPT TO CONTINUE!
::REM echo.
::REM pause
::REM cls


::This creates the folder structure for exporting of the point cloud.
md "C:\INLET\INLETXXXXX\TEMP\EXPORT"
::This creates a folder for the .igs file to perform cross-section & waviness analysis.
md "C:\INLET\MEASURED\InletXXXXX"
::This creates a folder in EIS ARCHIVE for archiving the raw data & analysis reports.
md "\\SE\data\PSC_CAMS_DATA\PSC_CAMS\COMPLETED_PRODUCTION_SURVEYS\EIS_ARCHIVE\LUXXX"
::This copies the SA Job File contents to the C:INLET & EIS ARCHIVE folders.
copy /Y "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\EIS_DATA" "C:\INLET\INLETXXXXX"
copy /Y "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\EIS_DATA" "\\SE\data\PSC_CAMS_DATA\PSC_CAMS\COMPLETED_PRODUCTION_SURVEYS\EIS_ARCHIVE\LUXXX"
cls
START "" "\\SE\data\PSC_CAMS_DATA\PSC_CAMS\COMPLETED_PRODUCTION_SURVEYS\EIS_ARCHIVE\LUXXX"
cls

::This is a User prompt.
::REM echo UPDATE NAMING CONVENTION OF ALL FOLDERS FOR UNIT NUMBER!
::REM echo.
::REM pause
::REM cls


::REM This is a User prompt.
::REM echo PRESS ANY KEY TO LAUNCH SPATIAL ANALYZER!
::REM echo.
::REM pause
::REM cls
::This launches the Spatial Analyzer64.exe 
START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\New River Kinematics\SpatialAnalyzer 2015.07.28_6769\x64\Spatial Analyzer64.exe"

::REM This is a User prompt.
::REM echo DRAG AND DROP SA JOB FILE FROM C:\INLET INTO SA ENVIRONMENT!
::REM echo.
::REM echo EXPORT POINT CLOUD TO C:\INLET\INLETXXXXX\TEMP\EXPORT!
::REM echo.
::REM echo DO NOT INCLUDE POINT LABELING!
::REM echo.
::REM pause
::REM cls

::This is a User prompt.
echo OPEN SA FILE AND EXPORT THE POINT CLOUD!
echo.
echo NEXT STEP WILL CLOSE Spatial Analyzer!
echo.
pause
cls

TASKKILL /F /IM Spatial*
::This is a User prompt.
echo EIS ANALYSIS FILE FOLDER PREP FINISHED!
echo HAVE A NICE DAY!  :-)
echo.
pause
cls
```

I have tried this, after the copy out has completed and it still doesn't work. It just closes the batch. I have also tried for loops like this and it still doesn't work.

```
pause
CD "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\EIS_DATA"
for /d "delims='LU'" %%a in (CSR_SC_748_314A6100-4_737_Max_Inlet_Assy_EIS_LU*) do set d=%%a
pause
echo
echo. d : %d%
echo.
pause

set "str1=INLET00"
set "str2=%str1%%d%"
set "str3=Inlet00%d%"
pause
echo.%str2%
echo.%str3%
pause
```

Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: Are these empty subdirectories? Are you aware that in winbatch, directorynames are case-insensitive, so `PART00000` and `Part00000` are one and the same directory?

Comment: Yesterday in effectively the same question, _which should have been edited instead of starting this question_, you said the file was called, `CSR_SC_748_314A6100-4_737_Max_Inlet_Assy_EIS_LU106_06232017.xit64` so does it have an extension or not? Are there multiple files to be read or just one, if there are several where are they, together or in several locations?

Comment: @Magoo There are 2 utilities that use both directories and need to be for the same inlet name. If the cases are the same then the first utility breaks. Initially, the C:\INLET00106 directory has the .xit64 data file in it  at the start for the first utility and the C:\INLET\MEASURED\Inlet00106 remains empty, until the first utility finishes and then a file that was generated from the first utility gets copied into that directory to run the second utility.

Comment: @Compo Yes, the file has the extension (.xit64) and I have changed some of the naming of my folder structure, so I figured that it would be easier to start a new question, as simply as I could. My apologies for the mix-up.

Comment: I should just post the batch that I have now, in it's entirety. It does everything that I want it to do, except for renaming the three folders.

Comment: You should post that script but only by editing your question, do not add it to a comment, new answer or external site.

Comment: To rename directories use the [`move` command](http://ss64.com/nt/move.html)...

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DavidPostill How's this? I have tried many different ways that I thought would work and have had no success.